# Steam Submission Times

Tags: steam

I was wondering if anyone has released or tried to release on Steam and how much time it took Steam to respond to your game submissions, I cant find any info about it on their website and its been over a month now since I have submitted and have yet to even get a confirmation email.

Is this to be expected from sources such as these? Ive sent them two emails so far at 3 weeks apart and have to make a decision on what to do with the game and can not wait much longer.

Comment: From what I've heard, the best way to get on Steam is to successfully release your game elsewhere, and THEN get on Steam (or have a proven track record of successful games)

Comment: Is your game nearly complete?

Answer (score 7):

I'm already on Steam and it can be hard to get a reply from Valve sometimes. They also have a LOT of turnaways - and their policy is to not tell you why. Which kind of sucks.

Comment: One of the best ways to keep getting wrong material is exactly not telling the reasons for refusing them. Pretty stupid.

Comment: @Lo'oris I would +50billion this.